# How can I create a single login page?

Tags: 7, users

I do not want to display a login block or link on every page. I would instead like to create a single login page accessible from  http://example.com/login. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

/user/login exists by default; you could use that.

Comment: And if it must be at yoursite.com/login, you can create a path alias.

Comment: @Berdir i think that is what i want. how can i do that? making without `?` and `=` just write the user name or something else

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Is your URL currently something like `?q=some/path'? Then you have to enable Clean URL's. Or do you want to pass the username of the user that should be logged in to that page? Anyway, you can create an alias by enabling the Path module (if it isn't already) and then go to admin/config/search/path.

Comment: @Berdir  yes my URL is like `?q=some/path` and i'm using drupal 7 there is no `admin/config/search/path` my admin controller. if it is possible to change this URL `?q=some/path` to something else, that will be cool. and that is what i want. thanks,

Comment: These are two completely different things. If you have URL's like that, this means that you don't have clean URL's enabled. See http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls for more information. After you enable them, the URL I gave you should work. But in general yes, url aliases allow you do define arbitrary URL's which can point to any internal url (user/login in this case).

Comment: You may need to enable path module as well...